# events in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

controller

```
 IEnumerable<SelectListItem> process = 
    from proc in         
        XDocument.Load("Processes.xml").Descendants("Process")  
          select new SelectListItem
          {
              Text = (string)proc.Element("ConfigFile")
          };
    ViewBag.process = process;
```

view

```
<p>@Html.DropDownList("process")</p>
```

I want to handle an event on item selected in the dropdown list
I Googled a bit and people say there is no regular event handler like normal ASP or WinForm application

I'm not familiar with javascript and jquery but i could understand a code

Comment: Define "normal" - HTTP is a stateless request/response mechanism. ASP.NET MVC is more "normal" for HTTP than ASP WebForms is - which is a leaky abstraction to make web development more like WinForms development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put this DropDown inside a form and use javascript to subscribe to its `onchange` event and manually submit this form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController"))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("process", Model.Items, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
}
```

this will POST the selected value to the SomeAction where you could retrieve it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string process)
{
    // the process argument will contain the selected value from the dropdown
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darin, pretty neat

Comment: in the @using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController"))

some controller i will give it my controller name right?

in public ActionResult SomeAction(string process)

do this method have to have a return type?

actually i want to open a new page with a textbox in response to the dropdownlist item selected

Comment: Yes, you should give your controller name. So for example if you have a controller called `HomeController`, you would pass `Home`. And of course that your action should return an ActionResult, all controller actions do. You should return some response to the browser, shouldn't you?

Comment: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

i got this error on  @Html.DropDownList("process", new { onchange = "this.form.submit(); "})

Comment: I have updated my answer. You should pass the available items as second argument to the `DropDownList` helper. If you are using ViewBag or ViewData you could also specify that: `@Html.DropDownList("process", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.process, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })` but with a strongly typed view model it's much better.